# React Intl Formatting date

Tags: reactjs, intl

i have incoming date in exactly like this string:

```
myDate= ' 2017-05-05T12:24:06+0000'
```

i am using FormattedDate from 'react-intl' to achieve my desired format

```
12:24, 5 May 2017
```

But with this code:

```
<FormattedDate
  value={myDate}
  day="numeric"
  month="long"
  year="numeric"
  hour="numeric"
  minute="numeric"/>
```

i am getting this :

```
May 5, 2017, 12:24
```

i must be doing something wrong. Or misunderstood docs. Can you advise me ?

I

Comment: Can you add a link to the mentioned docs?

Comment: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#date-formatting-apis

Comment: It seems all correct to me, also judging from this: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Components#formatteddate , you cannot change the standard default format, or pass a custom format along?

Comment: You can change the style of every component but you cannot change their order. The order is defined by i18n.

Answer (score 9):

Try to combine with [FormattedTime](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Components#formattedtime) of the same library

```
<FormattedTime value={myDate}/>,&nbsp;<FormattedDate
  value={myDate}
  day="numeric"
  month="long"
  year="numeric"/>
```